# Почему карусель пропускает последний элемент в цикле и как исправить?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, плагин, карусель

Есть реализованный функционал, завязанных на гибриде карусели и табов - [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/tsg54995/)
Перенес его **wordpress** и задаю элементы через [плагин произвольных полей](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). Все бы хорошо, но теперь все работает (крутится карусель) только до предпоследнего элемента после чего возвращается к первому. Как этот момент подправить?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="">

                  <?php $test = new WP_Query([
                        'post_type'     => 'gates',
                        'post_status'   => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                        'order'         => 'ASC'
                    ]); ?>
          <?php $i=0; ?>

      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">      
          <?php while($test->have_posts()): ?>
                    <?php $test->the_post(); ?>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>"<?php if($i==0) : echo ' class="active"'; endif; ?>>
        <a data-toggle="pill" class="js-link js-link-<?php echo $i; ?>" href="#<?php echo ++$i; ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></a>
        </li>

                                    <?php endwhile ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query() ?>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <?php $i = 0;
          while($test->have_posts()): ?>
                    <?php $test->the_post(); ?>

                        <?php 
              $gallery = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gallery_types', true);
              if($gallery):
              $images = get_field('gallery_types');
              if( $images ): ?>
                <div class="item <?php if($i==0) : echo "active"; endif; ?>">
                  <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
                <?php $i++; ?>
              <?php endif;  endif;                      ?>

          <?php endwhile ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query() ?>
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"></a>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Скорее всего нужно JS смотреть, который отвечает за работу карусели. Тот код, который вы дали выводит кол-во картинок (структуру карусели)

Comment: @eugene_v `js` как такового нет, вернее он берется полностью из встроенной карусели `bootstrap`. тут либо у мня подозрение на `$i++` и `++$1`, либо на условия - в первом случае выводятся управляющие элементы просто по наличию всех постов `gate`s, а во втором условие зависимости от наличия `$gallery` и `$images` в нем, но в каждом из них `$images` присутствуют

Comment: Bootstrap.js подключен?

Comment: В Fiddle все работает правильно, а на сайте не корректно работает карусель? Ищите проблему на сайте! Смотрите консоль, что в ошибках. У вас в Fiddle есть `HTML, JS, CSS` вы все перенесли? Ссылку на сайт дайте. Попробуйте еще в JS который в Fiddle все знаки `$` поменять на `jQuery`

Comment: @eugene_v еще раз проверил - в одном из элементов не сохранилась галерея. добавил - решило проблему! единственный момент - вот думаю какое условие еще поставить, чтобы она в будущем не повторилась при случайном удалении всех изображений элемента

Comment: тут вопрос в том, что нужно выводить если нет изображений

Comment: @eugene_v пустое поле. это во много раз лучше, чем косячная карусель

Answer (score 0):

В одном из элементов не сохранилась галерея изображений - отсюда и ошибка, сам код правильный. добавил галерею изображений - решило проблему